# git bat password not working in cmd

Tags: git

I run bat for git I write

```
git checkout master
git add .
git pull
pause
```

http://postimg.org/image/piy9vwxvd/

and when I got to the part I need to fill the password is stuck
I cant write anything.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try just typing the password and pressing enter? Unix systems are known for hiding the password by not displaying _anything_ when typing it (essentially making it look like it doesn't work when no characters appear).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I'm pasting the password using `Ctrl+Shift+v` or by right click > paste. It automatically goes to another line and say invalid. But it works fine when I use some graphics tool like `git gui`. However, it doesn't solve my problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this, by caching your password. Therefore you have to options:

**Option 1: Caching your credentials**

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Because I assume your OS is windows, you should use `wincred` instead:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Then you can set a timeout (default is 15 minutes), to surpress the password-request for at least one hour:

```
git config --global credential.helper --timeout=3600
```

That means, before running your batch-file, you have to manually  `git pull` (or something else, that requires entering your passphrase). Then, the passphrase is cached for an hour.

**Option 2: Storing your credentials**

You use a credentials file to store your credentials by running this. But be aware, that this method stores your data as plain text on your filesystem:

```
git config --global credential.helper store --file ~/.credentials-file
```

You will find more information on this topic in the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).